# NuGet Package generated from Visual Studio using MSBuild adds fixed path for PDB Sources

Tags: c#, git, nuget, bitbucket

I am new to NuGet package creation and not sure where I am going wrong. I have created a nuget package for assembly project and added the below code to .csproj file that lets me create .nupkg (with pdb) and .snupkg file.

As my source code is on bitbucket I have installed Microsoft.SourceLink.Bitbucket.Git (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SourceLink.Bitbucket.Git) and followed their guildelines from https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink. However, they don't support bitbucket cloud yes and there is open ticket (https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/issues/878) that can be seen.

```
<PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
<EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
<IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
<SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
```

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)'==''">Release</Configuration>
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
    <PackageId>TEST</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>1</PackageVersion>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <Authors>TEST</Authors>
    <PackageIcon>TEST.png</PackageIcon>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>false</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <PackageDescription>TEST</PackageDescription>
    <PackageTags>TEST</PackageTags>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>TEST.</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <copyright>TEST</copyright>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="TEST_1" Version="1" />
    <None Include="Resources\TEST.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The problem I am facing here is that when NuGet package gets created it adds bitbucket cloud api url for source link which is due to the nuget package Microsoft.SourceLink.Bitbucket.Git and when I try to source link it fails obviously because of that open ticket I mentioned above, but then it tries to fall back and for some reason there is another PDB source path that is D:\ drive.

This is fixed path how can I change it to be relative so that if any other developer installs this can use it ? Or just don't have any path like this D:\

[NuGet Package Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8ov7.png)